# Mysql- Get the records that are less than 24 hours from a table and insert in to another table when condition satisfied

Tags: mysql

I have a master table as:

```
id(PRIMARY KEY) customername    zipcode identitynumber  createdtimestamp
ABC                 JOHN         91421     12346          2:09:31 AM
DEF                 CARTER       91421     12346    2:09:31 AM
PQR                AURTHUR       13133     767676   2:09:31 AM
```

and another table child as below.

```
ID(PRIMARY) customername    zipcode identitynumber  
xyz           peter          91421  12346   
MNO           CARTER         91421  12346
```

I want to get all the records from master table that are having `createdtimestamp` is less than 24 hours and insert in to child table only if `zipcode`, `identitynumber` match but not `customername`. Basically inserting various names in child table having same `zipcode` and  `identitynumber` and primary key of master table. So, finally child table should has:

```
ID(PRIMARY) customername    zipcode identitynumber  
xyz          peter            91421 12346   
MNO          CARTER           91421 12346   
ABC          JOHN             91421 12346
```

I tried with below query but failing as primary key violation even though child tables doesn't have primary key.

```
insert into childtable
    (ID,customername,zipcode,identitynumber)
    select
    master.id ,
    master.customername,
    child.zipcode,
    child.identitynumber
    FROM   childtable  child
    inner JOIN mastertable master ON master.CREATED_TIMESTAMP > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    and master.identitynumber = child.identitynumber 
    AND master.zipcode = child.zipcode
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1  FROM childtable existingchild
      WHERE  existingchild.identitynumber = master.identitynumber
      AND existingchild.customername  = master.customername
      AND existingchild.zipcode  =  master.zipcode);
```

Please advise with best query.

Comment: `NOT EXITS` should be `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: **even though child tables doesn't have primary key.** Your diagram shows that it has Primary Key = `ID`.

Comment: Thanks for comment!.child tables has xyz, MNO as primary key, but for output ABC is primary key from master table

Comment: Try doing just the `SELECT` and see what it returns, then compare that to the existing contents of `child`.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'ABC' for key 'PRIMARY'. even though ABC is not in child table

Comment: Does the `SELECT` return multiple rows with ID = ABC? The duplicate occurs when it tries to insert the second one.

Comment: Yes, SELECT is returning multiple rows. I am testing with distinct.

Comment: If the rows have different `zipcode` or `identitynumber`, DISTINCT won't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes! if it same then working file else failing again

Comment: You need to come up with a criteria to select which child row should be returned by the join when there are multiple, and put that into the `SELECT`. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1